# Starting a serverless docker container sibling from inside docker

Tags: docker, serverless

So I'm trying to start a serverless sibling container from the main contianer. I've volume binded /var/run/docker.sock to /var/run/docker.sock

`$ docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' webapp`

Output: `[{bind  /var/run/docker.sock /var/run/docker.sock   true rprivate}]`

And in my dockerfile (`FROM ubuntu:bionic`) I've installed docker with the same bit of code that I used to install docker on my local machine (also ubuntu bionic).

```
RUN apt -y install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common && \
 curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add - && \
 add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable" && \
 apt-get -y install docker.ce && \
 getent group docker || sudo groupadd docker
```

Regular docker commands are working fine.

However `serverless invoke local --docker -f function --data '{MY_DATA}'` isn't working and I'm given the response:

'Please start the Docker daemon to use the invoke local Docker integration.'

Comment: `service` and `systemctl` more or less don't work in Docker, and in this setup you're not running a separate Docker daemon anyways.  Can you run basic Docker commands; if not, can you show an actual command you're running and the actual error you're getting?

Comment: (Remember that, if you can run any Docker command at all, you can `docker run -v/:/host busybox cat /host/etc/shadow` or worse and trivially root the host.  Be really careful with basic security things, and reconsider whether you _actually_ need to directly launch a container, or whether just making a network connection to a container that's already running will work just as well.  Job queues like RabbitMQ can also help some common cases.)

Comment: @DavidMaze hi thanks, yeah it seems docker commands do actually work. I thought they didn't as serverless was failing. I'm doing this because I want to be able to use serverless invoke with the --docker flag. Security shouldn't be an issue since this is for development environments only.

Comment: I'll edit my question

Comment: are you running the webapp container in privileged mode?

Comment: I doubt it, I'm using docker-compose, think it'll make a difference?